# Operator == cannot be applied to 'Long' and 'Int' in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, operator-keyword

I'm attempting to implement parts of Mike Penz' NavigationDrawer (https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer) in Kotlin. Since then I've run into only a few issues, primarily with operators. Here is part of the code to instantiate the drawer itself. Android Studio doesn't throw any errors except where I'm using the == operator on int and Long variables:

```
        // Create the Drawer
        result = DrawerBuilder()
                .withSliderBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(applicationContext, R.color.top_header))
                .withActivity(this)
                .withToolbar(toolbar)
                .withHasStableIds(true)
                .withItemAnimator(AlphaCrossFadeAnimator())
                .withAccountHeader(headerResult!!)
                .addDrawerItems(
                        PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_profile).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_user).withIdentifier(1).withSelectable(false).withIconColor(ContextCompat.getColor(applicationContext, R.color.icon_grey)).withTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(applicationContext, R.color.stroke)),
                        PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_create).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_paint_brush).withIdentifier(2).withSelectable(false).withIconColor(ContextCompat.getColor(applicationContext, R.color.icon_grey)).withTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(applicationContext, R.color.stroke)),
                        PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_yaanich_news).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_newspaper_o).withIdentifier(3).withSelectable(false).withIconColor(ContextCompat.getColor(applicationContext, R.color.icon_grey)).withTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(applicationContext, R.color.stroke)),
                        PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_my_groups).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_users).withIdentifier(4).withSelectable(false).withIconColor(ContextCompat.getColor(applicationContext, R.color.icon_grey)).withTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(applicationContext, R.color.stroke)),
                        PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_settings).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_cog).withIdentifier(5).withSelectable(false).withIconColor(ContextCompat.getColor(applicationContext, R.color.icon_grey)).withTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(applicationContext, R.color.stroke))
                )
                .withOnDrawerItemClickListener { view, position, drawerItem ->

                    if (drawerItem != null) {
                        var intent: Intent? = null
                        if (drawerItem.identifier == (1) {
                            intent = Intent(this, UserProfileActivity::class.java)
                        } else if (drawerItem.identifier == 2) {
                            intent = Intent(this, YeetActivity::class.java)
                        } else if (drawerItem.identifier == 3) {
                            intent = Intent(this, RssActivity::class.java)
                        } else if (drawerItem.identifier == 4) {
                            intent = Intent(this, GroupsActivity::class.java)
                        } else if (drawerItem.identifier == 5) {
                            intent = Intent(this, UserSettingsActivity::class.java)
                        }
                        if (intent != null) {
                            this.startActivity(intent)
                        }
                    }
                    false
                }
                .withSavedInstance(savedInstanceState)
                .withShowDrawerOnFirstLaunch(true)
                .build()

        RecyclerViewCacheUtil<IDrawerItem<*, *>>().withCacheSize(2).apply(result!!.recyclerView, result!!.drawerItems)

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            result!!.setSelection(21, false)
            headerResult!!.activeProfile = profile
        }
    }
```

**Errors:**

`if (drawerItem.identifier == (1)`

`if (drawerItem.identifier == 2)`

`Operator == cannot be applied to 'Long and' 'Int'`

Comment: Unlike Java, Kotlin does not automatically promote numbers to wider types. You have to explicitly use the same types for these comparisons. Franscesc gave the correct answer, but if your int was stored in a variable, you would do `if (drawerItem.identifier == id.toLong())`.

Answer (score 173, accepted):

Simply use long on your right side

```
if (drawerItem.identifier == 1L)
```

Edit: the reason this is required is that Kotlin does not promote Ints to Longs (or, more generally, does not widen types); on the left side we had a Long and on the right side we had an Int, which lead to the error. Explicitly indicating that the right side is a Long fixes the error.

Comment: The L explicitly casts declares the `1` as a `Long` type so they can be compared now. "Explicitly indicating that the right side is a Long fixes the error."

Comment: How broadly true is the statement "Kotlin does not promote/widen types"? Other things do work, like ordered comparisons and the elvis operator. For example, `if (someLongValue > 1)` works (ditto `>=`, `<`, and `<=`), and `someNullableLongValue ?: 0` works and has type `Long`.

Comment: @kbolino there is no type promotion, but most operations (e.g. >=, <, etc) are actually functions, which are overloaded for all type combinations to do what's correct

Answer (score 2):

For interest, another solution would be to use `compareTo()`. [compareTo](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-long/compare-to.html) returns zero if the values are equal, negative if its less than the other, or positive if its greater than the other:

```
 if(drawerItem.identifier.compareTo(1) == 0)   "Equals"
```

Comment: For what it's worth, testing for -1 or 1 is not the same as testing for negative or positive.

Answer (score 2):

If the above solution didn't work for you,
try **explicitly** converting the value on right to the particular *wider* type on left side

```
num = 5.7
if (num == 4.toDouble()) {
    //some code
}
```

Every number type supports the following conversions:

- toByte(): Byte
- toShort(): Short
- toInt(): Int
- toLong(): Long
- toFloat(): Float
- toDouble(): Double
- toChar(): Char

Answer (score 0):

if you facing problem of 
< **operator != not applied to long and int** >
solve it Simply using long on your right side 
ie value!= 1L
thats it..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure when you are comparing Double with any number like myDouble == 5 it will not work until you add .0 at the end. It is because Kotlin guesses the type from the entered number and it will consider 5 as int and myDouble as double and will product same error

So, always explicitly make the comparing variable same of other variable

```
drawerItem.identifier == (1.0)
```